# Report Viewer 8.0 Rendering Issues in IE9

Tags: c#-2.0

We've had created **SSRS 2008 SQL Reports/Report Viewer 8.0** in a web app.  As of **IE9**, the rendering of the report and handling of it within the report viewer changed drastically from our prior experience.

Thus, our once very nice looking functional app has suddenly turned into a something that looks amatuerish ... to be kind about it.

I need to fix this before our next release, and I was hoping someone had encountered at least some of these issues before and had some hints.

I first noticed the rendering problems in the venerable **Report Viewer 8.0.0.0** that we had been relying on.

The major issue was a failure to respect the sizing of layouts, resulting in text wrapping and other undesired attempts by the renderer to display the report in a minimal shrunken space.

I decided that this was most likely because the aging ReportViewer didn't support more recent browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your reportviewer control in aspx page has following attributes

```
AsyncRendering="False" 
SizeToReportContent="True"
```